# Angular Material Primary, Accent, and Warn Colours Not Changing With Theme

Tags: angular, angular-material2

**Note: For anyone that finds this in the future, the solution from Emilien is only able to be used after angular material 10.0.0. I've examined the source code for the [Angular Components](https://github.com/angular/components) and determined that `@mixin angular-material-color` was included in 10.0.0. I will attempt to upgrade and see if that fixes my issue.**

**Update: After updating to angular 10 and material 10, the problem is still not resolved when using the `@mixin angular-material-color`.**

I have an angular site running angular 9.1.13, and angular material 9.1.3 with multiple themes defined in a `_themes.scss` file. I'm trying to change themes during run time, and can get most things to change, except for material components that use `color="primary"` or `color="accent"`.

When changing the theme, I change a variable called theme which is used in the `<app-root>` like this:

```
  template: `
    <simple-notifications></simple-notifications>
    <div *ngIf="!loading">
      <div [class]="service.theme"><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
    </div>
```

as well as update the class list on the overlay container from the documentation on the [Angular Material Site](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#multiple-themes-and-overlay-based-components).

Here is a snippet of what an additional theme in my `_themes.scss` looks like:

```
@import "~@angular/material/theming";
@import "_palette.scss";

@include mat-core();
/** main theme */
.. theme here ...

/* Additional Themes */
$dark-primary: mat-palette($mat-dark-primary, 800, 500, 900);
$dark-accent: mat-palette($mat-dark-accent, 700, 500, 900);
$dark-warn: mat-palette($mat-dark-warn);
$dark-theme: mat-dark-theme($dark-primary, $dark-accent, $dark-warn);

.dark-theme {
  ...other theme properties...
  @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
}
```

*Note: I have a `_palette.scss` file that is where the $mat-dark variables are coming from*

The screenshot below is an example of some material buttons using `color="accent"` but being unaffected by the accent colour in my custom palette. I would expect them to be the blueish colour of the image below that.

[image: Accent Button Colours]

[image: Accent Colour in use from class]

I know that I can put a class on each element instead of using `color="accent"`, but it would be a lot more convenient to not have to do that.

Comment: Try with `@include angular-material-color($dark-theme);`

Comment: @Emilien do I need to define the mixin for that? Getting a `SassError: no mixin named angular-material-color` when building

Comment: You can see it on the link you provided (Angular Material Site). Then you read "the `angular-material-theme` mixin should not be used multiple times as it generates styles for all configured theming system parts."

Comment: @Emilien maybe angular-material-color isn't a mixin available in 9.1.3, because I can't get it to build using that.

Comment: @Emilien after updating to angular 10 and material 10, using angular-material-color still doesn't change the primary, accent, and warning colours, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes across this same issue; the solution for me was to wrap each component in a `<div class="{{ service?.theme }}"></div>` which caused the colours to update accordingly.